# Failed to connect to SSIS (Local Activation permission)

Tags: ssis

I'm trying to connect to SSIS through SSMS but i keep getting this error:

> The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
>   {46063B1E-BE4A-4014-8755-5B377CD462FC}
>    and APPID 
>   {FAAFC69C-F4ED-4CCA-8849-7B882279EDBE}
>    to the user xx\xxxxxx SID (S-1-5-21-863774119-1135311350-5522801-23299) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.

I have added the permission using component services as stated in the error message (followed step-by-step guides for this), restarted the SSIS Service but i still get the error.
Am I missing something here or ?

EDIT: forgot to add the user to the " Distributed COM Users" group - dooh

Thx
/Nicolaj

Comment: forgot to add the user to the " Distributed COM Users" group - dooh

Comment: Mind linking to the step by step guide in case others come across this question? Also, you can always edit your own question to reflect the current state of the problem.

Comment: You might also have better luck with this question over on serverfault.com

Comment: this is the guide i followed: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337083.aspx I simply wasn't aware of step 1 - wonder how i could miss that :-D

Comment: still no connection problems. i cross my fingers that it worked... and will post again if it turns out that the problems come back

Comment: Excellent. Please post your link as an answer so the question can be resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the guide I followed: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337083.aspx

I wasn't aware of step 1.